# Sharepoint search returns nothing after configuring AAM

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, search-scope

There is a SharePoint intranet site `http://server_name:port` with DNS `xyz` pointed to `server_name`.

The issue could be related to  the way I have configured `AAM`. Here is the background about what was done.

- I added new binding in IIS with port 80 and host name `xyz`.
- Configured alternate access mapping for the site collection by adding
  new mapping for intranet with `http://xyz`.
- There is a search    application configured and I had to include
  `http://xyz` in the search scope to get the items in the site
  crawled. The items crawled was 0    when the search scope was default
  address of the site.
- I have not    removed `http://server_name:port` from the scope and
  hence i get this    crawl error.

> This item could not be crawled because the crawler could not connect to the repository

Now I access the site using `http://xyz` and try a search query, the result returns nothing!

I checked the log it seems the items are getting queried. I also get this error in the LOG

> Error getting element ProxyUrl: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: xDoc 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.LocationConfiguration.getElements(XmlDocument xDoc, String elementName, String nameSpace)
>        at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.LocationConfiguration.getElementString(XmlDocument xDoc, String elementName, String nameSpace)

Please let me know how to get over this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set **Sever Name Mappings** in the Search Service Application. Essentially, you specify the address at which the content will be crawled (this can be `http://server_name:port`) and the address (`http://xyz`) that will be displayed in search results.

Its quite unlikely you need to set bindings in your IIS if the DNS name has been configured correctly to point to your SharePoint WFE or the NLB (if used) and alternate access mappings are configured correctly. Just ensure your public url for the default zone remains the same as the DNS name. Your internal url should be `(http://servername:port)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I had to add the mapping in Search service, also the second part of your answer prompted me to make correction on how i had configured AAM.

Comment: Hi AroD, googling around i tumbled here. Unfortunately above has not worked for me.
I have 2 internal URLS (http://servername & http://abc.ddd.com) and one public url (http://abc.ddd.com) in my AAM. Also have added Server name Mapping as 'Address for indexing = http://servername' and 'Address for  display results = http://abc.ddd.com)
What could i bee missing. My search works on server but not outside server

thank you