# Search result does not reflect HNSC

Tags: 2013, search

Background:

- I have a farm with two web applications. One is the default created during install, with the address of `http://machine`
- I created a second web application for HNSC, with the address of `http://machine:81`.
- A site collection exists at `http://www.fqdn.net`, which is hosted within the host header web application at `http://machine:81`
- In Search, the start address is `http://machine:81`. (I don't want to update the search configuration every time another HNSC is created.)

Problem

- In search results, the Path property is being returned as `http://www.fqdn.net:81`
- (The SPSiteURL property in the search result for the same item is correct)

Question

- How do I get the search results to use the HNSC url without the port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server Name Mappings come to mind. In search you can just tell it, it the crawler is crawling at this address, spit out the search results with a different address.

References: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/02/20/beware-crawling-the-non-default-zone-for-a-sharepoint-2013-web-application.aspx

[Sharepoint search returns nothing after configuring AAM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41567/sharepoint-search-returns-nothing-after-configuring-aam)

**EDIT**: According to this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx

You should really using a top level host header web application on a default port (80/443) if you are going to use HNSC in that web application. I think that's your issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think server name mappings may mask the symptoms, it won't fix the underlying problem. And the link to blogs.msdn.com cautions against using the to fix sp2013.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I was just IM'ing Kirk yesterday - why didn't I ask him! Thanks for the link!